# End = "" results in % at the end

Tags: python

I'm a beginner who just learned Python for 3 days.
The result value of end = " " is % at the end. This problem didn't occur until yesterday.

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i, end=" ")
```

It works normally at the terminal or idle.I also deleted the VSCode and re-installed it.
What's the problem? I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: This will happen in a zsh shell. Others (sh, bash, ksh etc.) will behave differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not really there, and it's not coming from Python.  When you run a command from `zsh` and the output of that command doesn't include a trailing newline, zsh displays that inverse-video percent sign to signal to the user that the newline is missing.[image: non-Python demo]:

Answer (score 0):

That's a result of your shell.  It prints `%` to notify you that the command output did not end in a newline.

Otherwise the output would be merged on the same line as your next shell prompt, which looks ugly.